# jQuery not working for custom checkbox on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, jquery

I am looking to create a custom checkbox field on the checkout process that a customer can click to define if they are a business customer or a consumer.

To do so I made a module with the file **`SomeProcessor.php`**:

```
    <?php
namespace BusinessCheckout\CustomCheckout\Block\Checkout;

class SomeProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custom_checkbox'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => '.custom_checkbox',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'custom-field'
            ],
            'dataScope' => '.custom_checkbox',
            'label' => 'Is this a business order? Business T&C\'s apply.',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 50,
            'id' => 'custom-field'
        ];


        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
?>
```

All good so far and the **checkbox appears** on the checkout page as expected.

Now I've added the following **jQuery** to the footer of the site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').attr('checked', false)
  jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);

  jQuery('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').click(function() {

    if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == true) {

      jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", false);

    } else if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {

      jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);

    }

  });

});

</script>
```

It seems working when I enter it directly into console but not on the site footer.

The expected functionality is to have the **checkbox unchecked** when the **page loads** and the **company field disabled**. Then if the user **clicks the checkbox** the **company field becomes enabled**.

Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

I have updated your code from `'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',` To `'component' => 'BusinessCheckout_CustomCheckout/js/form/element/customCheckbox',`.

```
    <?php
namespace BusinessCheckout\CustomCheckout\Block\Checkout;

class SomeProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custom_checkbox'] = [
             'component' => 'BusinessCheckout_CustomCheckout/js/form/element/customCheckbox',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => '.custom_checkbox',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'custom-field'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'custom_checkbox',
            'label' => 'Is this a business order? Business T&C\'s apply.',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 50,
            'id' => 'custom-field'
        ];


        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
?>
```

Now create new `customCheckbox.js` file in this path 'BusinessCheckout/CustomCheckout/frontend/web/js/form/element/' And put tthis content in that new `customCheckbox.js` JS file.

```
 define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
    'jquery',
    'uiRegistry'
], function (abstractComponent,jQuery,uiRegistry) {
    uiRegistry.get("checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.company", function (element) {
        element.disable();
    });
    return abstractComponent.extend({
        hasChanged: function () {
            if (this.value() == true) {
                jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", false);
            } else if (this.value() == false) {
                jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);
            }
            return this._super();
        }
    });
});
```

That `hasChanged` methode will call while click for check and un-check.

Please run `php bin/magento cache:flush` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command after the changes.

Comment: This works in some way however once the page load the checkbox is unchecked and the field is enabled. Only once clicked and unclicked does it function as expected. It should be so that the page loads with the checkbox unchecked and the field disabled.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome, that updated code works perfectly! Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Welcome, happy to help you and I learn new thing about `uiRegistry`. we can run custom script after load all UI JS and Content.

Answer (score 5):

**Try this code**

Main issue is wrong jquery event.

**Your code**

```
jQuery('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').click(function() {
```

**Replace with**

```
jQuery(document).on('change', 'form input[name="custom_checkbox"]', function(e) {
```

**Full code**

```
<script>
require(['jquery'], function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').attr('checked', false)
        $('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);
        $(document).on('change', 'form input[name="custom_checkbox"]', function(e) {
            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {

              $('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", false);

            } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {

              $('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Alexander try this code its work

Answer (score 1):

Try to use script like this way:

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function(jQuery){ 
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').attr('checked', false)
  jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);

  jQuery('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').click(function() {

    if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == true) {

      jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", false);

    } else if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {

      jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);

    }

  });
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Still no luck with this unfortunately. Same as before, it works when inputted directly into console but when in the footer nothing happens.

Comment: If it helps at all here is a link to the site that might give a better idea of what's going on: https://bit.ly/1resXVE

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').attr('checked', false)
        $('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);

        $('.checkout-index-index form').on('click', 'input[name="custom_checkbox"]', function() {
            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                $('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", false);
            } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
                $('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

You need use setTimeout for this as Magento 2 load checkout through knockout. On page load elements are not present in the DOM due to this your jquery is not working. You can adjust the time 3000 to your value by checking the time which is perfect for rendering.

Comment: No luck with this unfortunately, even after increasing setTimeout. It seems to work fine in console but when in the footer/header nothing.

Comment: Can you add custom js file through XML and add the above code to that custom js file and test again

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep below code in your JS,

```
<script>
require(["jquery","domReady!"],function(jQuery) {
    jQuery('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').attr('checked', false)
    jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);

    $('body').on("click",'form input[name="custom_checkbox"]',function() {
        if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == true) {
          jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", false);
        } else if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {
          jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite `form.html` knockout template of `Magento_Checkout` in your theme.

**app\design\frontend\Vendorname\Themename\Magento_Checkout\web\template\billing-address\form.html**

replace below div

```
<div class="billing-address-form" data-bind="fadeVisible: isAddressFormVisible">
```

to

```
<div class="billing-address-form" data-bind="fadeVisible: isAddressFormVisible, afterRender: renderedHandler">
```

Rewrite **billing-address.js** in your theme

**app\design\frontend\Vendorname\Themename\Magento_Checkout\web\js\view\billing-address.js**

add below function in above js file

```
       /**
         * after form render handler
         *
         */
        renderedHandler: function (elements, data) {
         require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function(jQuery){ 
          jQuery(document).ready(function() {

          jQuery('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').attr('checked', false)
          jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);

          jQuery('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').click(function() {

          if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == true) {

              jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", false);

          } else if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {

              jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);

          }

          });

         });
         });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery'], function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var flag = 0;
        var existCondition = setInterval(function() {
            if ($('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').length) {
                if ($('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').prop("checked") == true) {
                    $('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
                    flag++;
                }
            }
            if ($('form input[name="company"]').length) {
                if ($('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled") == false) {
                    $('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);
                    flag++;
                }
            }

            if(flag == 2) {
                clearInterval(existCondition);
            }
        }, 100);

        $(document).delegate('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]', 'click change', function () {
            if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == true) {

                jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", false);

            } else if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {

                jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in footer js it will work

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function()  {
  //add your code here        
});
```